# Proper use of Ecmascript 6 syntax: "=>" or "function(){...}

Tags: javascript, function, syntax, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to follow a proper code style using ES6 but I'm having some trouble understanding when should I use "=>".
Until now I'm using arrows for callbacks, where before I would write an anonymous function.

But my question is: Should I use arrows also when declaring a function?

```
function myFunc(param) { ... }
```

Should be changed to:

```
myFunc: (param) => {...}
```

(?)

Thanks for reading, I hope this question helps also others struggling with using ES6 in their code.

Comment: depends on whether you want to encapsulate `this` from where it was declared

Comment: @NinaScholz: No reason you can't use recursion in arrow functions.

Comment: @NinaScholz: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Also related: [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196)